# Location-specific vs location-centric

Tags: american-english

May I ask which of the two is correct:

1) If your design is location-centric, please specify the location.
2) If your design is location-specific, please specify the location.

Thank you.

Comment: "specific," as you have it written there.  "centric" would be for an area, and not a single spot.  That's my take on it, anyway.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the context.

Location-centric is referring to the central point of an area of interest while Location-specific is the exact point of interest.